# How do I generate mipmap .png and model .obj files for LibGDX?

Tags: opengl-es, textures, libgdx, 3d-modelling, mipmaps

I'm playing a bit with LibGDX (OpenGL ES 2.0 wrapper for Android).

I found some sample code which used prepared files to load models and mipmap textures for them, e.g., at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/invaders/gdx-invaders/src/com/badlogic/gdxinvaders/RendererGL20.java it reads .obj file for the model and RGB565 format .png file to apply a mipmapped texture to it.

What is the best / easiest way for me to create these files?

I understand .obj files are generated by a bunch of tools (I installed Blender, Wings3D and Kerkythea so far), but which ones will be the most user friendly for someone unfamiliar with 3D modelling?

But more importantly, how do I produce a .png file with the mipmapped texture? The .png I looked at ( https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/invaders/gdx-invaders/data/ship.png ) seems to include different textures for each of the faces, probably created with some tool. I browsed through the menus for the 3 tools I have installed but didn't find an option to export such a .png file. What am I missing?

Comment: Not really an appropriate question for SO. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: "If your question generally covers …
    software tools commonly used by programmers
    practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

That being said, I reposted to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43888/how-do-i-generate-mipmap-png-and-model-obj-files-for-libgdx , it may belong better there.

Comment: Yeah, I think you will have more luck at gamedev is all, not trying to shoot you down or anything.

Comment: No worries :). BTW they pointed me to "UV mapping" - that is the method I think I'm looking for.